# Pivot single column with into multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I need help with a query to help me do the following:

I want to take the below format:

```
SalesOrderNumber    CustomName      Status  Start       End         CrewName
29002               Turner, Linda   Closed  2014-01-22  2014-01-24  Espinoza,H.
29002               Turner, Linda   Closed  2014-01-22  2014-01-24  Severt,C.
29002               Turner, Linda   Closed  2014-01-22  2014-01-24  Valladares,R.
```

and turn it into this:

```
SalesOrderNumber  CustomName      Status  Start       End         CrewName1   CrewName2  CrewName3
29002             Turner, Linda   Closed  2014-01-22  2014-01-24  Espinoza,H  Severt,C.  Valladares,R.
```

thank you all in advance!

Comment: What's the criteria for which rows get grouped together?  Is there a cap on the number of rows that will get grouped?  What have you done so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which SQL are you using? (MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL...)?

Comment: @ScottHunter grouping would be done on "SalesOrderNumber" and the cap would be no more than 6

Comment: What should happen when rows with the same SalesOrderNumber differ on any of CustomName, Status, Start or End?

Comment: @ScottHunter this shouldn't be an issue as customName, Status, start and end are all tied back to the unique SalesorderNumber

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT to get the result but you will want to also use a windowing function like `row_number()` to create a unique value for each row in the `SalesOrderNumber`.  This unique number will then be used to create your new columns:

```
select salesordernumber, customname, status, start, [end],
  Crew1 = [1], 
  Crew2 = [2], 
  Crew3 = [3]
from
(
  select salesordernumber, customname, status, start, [end], crewname,
    row_number() over(partition by salesordernumber
                      order by crewname) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(crewname)
  for seq in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db6a5/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

I do not 100% understand pivots, but I think this should work. It is based off a pivot we use here. If it does not work, I might have switched the CrewName and SalesOrderNumber in the Pivot.

*Note For four columns commented out you either need to join the outer query back to the table, or to include them in the pivot. I think both options work.

```
SELECT
    SalesOrderNumber
    --,CustomName
    --,Status
    --,Start
    --,End
    ,[1]
    ,[2]
    ,[3]

    FROM ( SELECT
            SalesOrderNumber
            ,CrewName

            FROM <TableName>

            ) As QueryToPivot


    PIVOT (MAX(QueryToPivot.CrewName) FOR QueryToPivot.SalesOrderNumber IN ([1],[2],[3])) As QueryToPivot
```